# What is the method for optimizing individual functions in a file in GCC 4.1.1?

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++, gcc, pragma

Various C / C++ compilers have `#pragma`s to control optimization.

For example:

**CodeWarrior**

```
#pragma optimization_level 0
void func_no_opt()
{
    // Some Work - not optimized
}

#pragma optimization_level 3
void func_full_opt()
{
    // Some Work - optimized
}
```

**MSVC**

```
#pragma optimize("g", off)
void func_no_opt()
{
    // Some Work - not optimized
}

#pragma optimize("g", on)
void func_full_opt()
{
    // Some Work - optimized
}

#pragma optimize("", on)
void func_default_opt()
{
    // Some Work - default optimizations
}
```

For purely performance reasons, I have a couple of functions that need to be optimized in all builds, including debug builds that are otherwise not optimized.

Is there a way in GCC (specifically 4.1.1) to do something similar to these other compilers?  Unfortunately, GCC 4.4 is not supported on my target platform (proprietary hardware) so I can not use the optimize attribute -- i.e. `__attribute__((optimize(...)))`.

Also, on the toolchain for this target platform, there is an auto-bulk-build tool; so it's also not possible to just split the functions off into a separate file and change the optimization parameters, since files within a project can be automatically combined for an increase in compilation and link speeds.  I would have to make a separate library of just those functions and have it be linked-in in order to do the split-off method.  This might be quite a bit more pain than it would be worth -- especially if there is a simpler method of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the `__attribute__((optimize(...)))` is the only means to control optimization per-function basis in GCC. Thus with GCC 4.1.1 splitting out a separate library of functions to be optimized is indeed your only option.

Comment: Ugghh.. I was hoping there'd be an easier way.  I guess I'll just have to suffer until they start supporting GCC 4.4 :-(

Answer (score 2):

With GCC 4.4 upwards, you can use optimisation pragmas, as detailed in
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("-O0")
int foo() {
  return bar;
}
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Comment: I noticed that in a class method this option only works if the #pragma is in the class declaration (.h file). It doesn't have an effect on the method definition (.cpp file).